# How to make waved progress bar in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8

I am beginner IOS developer and often see in design patterns that people use `Heart Beat or Waves` as the progression bar (i.e. song progress). Sometimes these `progress bars go around the`Album Art etc.

How can i achieve such thing? I am aware of `UISlider` combined with `AVAudioPlayer` but couldn't find anything to achieve such as following for song slider.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a custom View, and draw the vertical lines manually. The main procedure for reference:

```
import UIKit

class WavedProgressView: UIView {

    var lineMargin:CGFloat = 2.0
    var volumes:[CGFloat] = [0.5,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.6,0.4]

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    }

    override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet{
            self.drawVerticalLines()
        }
    }

    var lineWidth:CGFloat = 3.0{
        didSet{
            self.drawVerticalLines()
        }
    }

    func drawVerticalLines() {
        let linePath = CGMutablePath()
        for i in 0..<self.volumes.count {
            let height = self.frame.height * volumes[i]
            let y = (self.frame.height - height) / 2.0
            linePath.addRect(CGRect(x: lineMargin + (lineMargin + lineWidth) * CGFloat(i), y: y, width: lineWidth, height: height))
        }

        let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        lineLayer.path = linePath
        lineLayer.lineWidth = 0.5
        lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        lineLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
        self.layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
    }
}
```

The effect is:
[image]

And please make it more perfect by yourself, like: handling event, applying default and highlighted color etc.

Comment: @YunCHEN Any suggestions on how you would create an animated progress effect? I tried subclassing `CAShapeLayer` and overriding `draw(in:)` to provide the context with two paths: one for the standard bars, and one for the progress bars, but they both have the same color.